# Error on local env when require some file

Tags: php, path, require

I have some code in my project, when i'm using "require_once" function to call my database class, it work's on my production environnement, but not in my local environnement.

I try to change my php conf to be more like my prod env. But the only way i found is to patch my local version of code. 
PHP version are 7.2 on the both env. One on windows with a wamp server, One on Google Cloud Platform.

Code on local env :

```
require_once '../../models/Class.php';
$class = new Class();
```

Code on prod env :

```
require_once './models/Class.php';
$class = new Class();
```

I expect my code to work on the both environnement without conditions (like if on local then / else). Actual error on my local env when i'm using prod version was :

> Warning: require_once(./models/Class.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   './models/Class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Thanks !

Comment: What OS do you have locally and what OS do you have on the server? Make sure that your "require" calls uses the exact same casing on the files and folders. So if the class is called `class.php`, then you need to require `class.php` and not `Class.php`. Some OS's are case sensitive and some not. Right now, it's pretty hard to know if that's the issue since your code says: `models/class.php` while the error says that it can't find `models/Class.php`. Is there a typo in the question?

Comment: Yes it's a typo, i edit it ! Thanks.
Local env was windows and prod was on linux, the only thing changing between my both was ../.. on windows and ./ on Linux. I don't understand why ./ doesn't work on windows ...